# How to set full image in Absolute Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set image in AbsoluteLayout but it'll not display in full screen on G1 but when i run the same application in Nexus it is working properly.

I have set setContentView(new Test(this)) in my activity class. Test is my AbsoluteLayout class.

My code looks like :

```
public class Test extends AbsoluteLayout {public Test(Context context) {
   super(context);
   final RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
    final android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    rl.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.addView(rl, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(context);mImageView.setImageBitmap(((DataStorage)context.getApplicationContext()).getImage());
    this.addView(mImageView);   }}
```

Can anyone tell me that why i am not getting full image on G1 mobile screen?

Comment: Don't use AbsoluteLayout. Ever.

Also why are you creating an empty RelativeLayout inside your AbsoluteLayout?

You should probably just switch to defining your layouts in XML.

Comment: Yes you are right but in my application i want draw lines and rectangles on my activity.
In java you can extend only one class. And i want to access the method of onScrollChanged() event of AbsoluteLayout.
In Absolute layout you can paint on your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem that i have not set

`this.addView(mImageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));`